# What is the pattern called when you pass child dependencies down through parents constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, dependencies

Say you have a class `A` which creates a variable of type `B`. `B` in turn creates a variable of type `C` which finally depends on some other class `X`. A way to get X to C would be like so:

```
class A {
    public A(X x) { 
        this.b = new B(x);
    }
}

class B {
    public B(X x) { 
        this.c = new C(x);
        this.c.doSomethingWithX();
    }
}

class C {
    public C(X x) { 
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void doSomethingWithX() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

We can now instantiate A like so `new A(new X());` which finally allows the inner `C` to use it.

*What is this pattern of dependency passing called?* **And how can I avoid it?**

Comment: It's not a pattern. Why do you think it should be avoided? What problem does that cause?

Comment: Well it might be an anti-pattern then I guess. I want to avoid it because I end up with a big chain which can be hard to follow.

Comment: Then pass a B to A's constructor and pass a C to B's constructor. Additional value: you're now doing dependency injection, making the code easy to test.